# Is it possible to use XML syntax to create instance of a class by Scala macro?

Tags: xml, scala, macros

Scala has powerful macro support, but I've never used that. I just wondering is it possible: use XML syntax to create instance of a class by Scala macro?

Say I have defined a class:

```
class User(name:String, age:Int)
```

Then I want to instantiate it this way:

```
val user = macroHere(<User name="Freewind" age={100} />)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Your macro def will take the XML syntax as an argument, and then in the macro impl you'll be able to take apart this syntax and generate a constructor call accordingly. https://github.com/scalamacros/xml might be helpful for this purpose. Unfortunately, I don't have time to provide an end-to-end solution, but I hope that these pointers might be useful.